# Do ATB upgrades affect the overall charge time?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

In Final Fantasy 13-2, when you choose to upgrade the number of ATB slots you have, does this have any affect on the charge time? Does it remain constant(resulting in a longer amount of time to load the full bar) or does it increase at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From some experimenting i did myself a atb bar with 3 slots takes about 4.3 ~ 4.4 seconds to charge.
increasing the amount of gauges increased the times a little but not by a significant amount +- 0.2 seconds.

Here's a table of my findings

```
Atb slots | Recharge Time                    
----------------------------------------------
3         |   4.3 ~ 4.4 seconds
4         |   4.5 ~ 4.6 seconds
5         |   4.7 ~ 4.8 seconds
6         |   4.8 ~ 4.9 seconds
```

To answer your questions:

Yes upgrading the number of ATB slots does increase charge time. But at 6 charges you pretty much have an efficiency of around 180% compared to the charge speed at 3 slots

Comment: if anyone could confirm my findings that would be nice i took these with a stopwatch over the course of playing seeing i had a similar question while playing ffxiii and decided to keep track this time

Comment: I believe this is exactly how the first game worked, as well.  It takes a bit longer to fill the bar completely, but it's still quick enough that you're getting way more actions off in the same amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

to confirm, here are my recharge averages:

### ATB level | full recharge | recharge per bar

3         |      4.32     |       1.44

4         |      4.46     |       1.11

5         |      4.66     |       0.93

6         |      4.79     |       0.80