# What are the strongest weapons in the game?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

It seems like, just like the last game, this isn't quite a straightforward estimation.  There are a few variable options (although not QUITE as many as last time).  Which weapons should I shoot for at endgame, and what's the easiest way to get them?  Does which weapons I use depend specifically on what I'm doing (again, much like the first game)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on what type of battler you are. For example, you may wish to trade-off Attack/Magic for an ability to increase the `Chain` quicker which can be very helpful in certain battles.

However, the weapons with the highest base stats are:

- Serah: `Arcus Chronica` which has 140`ATK` and 200`MAG` and costs $150,000 (although less with fragment ability). You need `Adamantite` to buy this weapon off Chocolina (after end game) which you can get from Chocobo Racing in `Serendipity` or by defeating Long Gui in the `Archylite Steppe` and you must use two other weapons which you can get from defeating two of the quest bosses (Ochu and Immortal) in the same place under different weather conditions. You just speak to the guy by the weather machine to activate these quests.
- Noel: `In Paradisum` which has 200`ATK` and 140`MAG` and costs $150,000 and can be obtained in the same manner as Serahs items.

Lastly, you can also buy the `Chaos Crystal` from Serendipity and give this to Hope in Academia 4XX AF and he will give you either `OdinBlade`(Noel) or `OdinBolt`(Serah) and you can buy whichever one you don't get from Serendipity (for 10,000 coins) or from Chocolina. These can have up to 220`ATK/MAG` but it is dependant on the amount of fragments you have collected with 160 equalling the max 220 on the weapons.

Comment: Any weapons with particularly useful or notable passive abilities?

Comment: @Shinrai You can find a comprehensive list here: http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_XIII-2_Weapons

Comment: The wiki link is helpful, but we like to try to keep content on-site wherever possible, and I'm also interested in opinion of somebody who's actually used them.  For example: are the weapons that add the sixth ATB segment ever worthwhile?  If you think all that stuff is not worth bothering with, that's cool, I'm just really curious about that judgment.

Comment: @Shinrai I personally go for the most powerful weapons in the game, but I've struggled in the harder battles. I think that weapons/armour that increase your ATB rate can be very helpful being that there's no way to cast haste in the game. The sixth ATB segment could be very helpful for Ega/Aga spells allowing you to cast two lots of protection/debuff in one full turn

Comment: @Shinrai An additional ATB gauge strengthens Noel and Serah's finishing moves (Meteor Javelin, Ultima Arrow) so they are worthwhile. Adding ATB segments, while increasing the charge time a bit, also allow for more actions over a short period of time (in other words, time per ATB slot does not increase linearly).

Comment: @Shinrai also the charge time for the entire atb bar doesn't increase linearly but with a set amount per bar. the difference between 5 and 6 bars is only 0.2 seconds so for a 0.2 longer charge time you get an extra atb slot. more info here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51396/do-atb-upgrades-affect-the-overall-charge-time